# How to use existing mysql DB along with its migrations in sql, in the Django? What changes will need to do in the django for using the mysql db?

Tags: python, mysql, sql, django, django-rest-framework

I am already having one mysql database with a lot of data, of which tables and migrations are written in sql. Now I want to use the same mysql database  in django so that I can use the data in that database.I am expecting that there will not be need for making the migrations as I am not going to write the models in Django again, also what will be the changes/modification I will have to do. For eg: as in middlewares?. Can anyone please help me in this?

Answer (score 0):

From what I know there is no 100 % automatic way to achieve that.

You can use the following command

```
python manage.py inspectdb
```

It will generate a list of unmanaged models that you can export to a model.py file and integrate in your django project.

However it is not magical and there are a lot of edge cases so the generated list of model should be manually inspected before being integrated.

More info here : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-inspectdb